# Black screen flickering on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, ssd, amd-graphics

I have just installed ubuntu 20.04 on my machine. Specs are as follows:

```
i7 6700k
32GB ram
1TB NVME SSD
256GB Sata SSD
MSI Radeon RX580 8G
4K Samsung Screen
```

I keep having the screen go to black and then show the desktop again. It will flicker to black 2 or 3 times, then be fine for about a minute, and do the same.

I am dual booting windows currently, and on windows it runs 100% fine. So I thought, driver problem.

I installed the latest drivers from AMD, following the [installation steps provided on the website](http://amdgpu-install.readthedocs.io/), but the issue persists.

Here is a video of what's happening.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to stop it?

Answer (score 0):

I played around with configuration and decided to drop my refresh rate from 60 to 59,94Hz, and it seems to have solved the problem.

For other non-experienced Ubuntu users: `Settings` -> `Displays` and set `Refresh Rate` to 59,94Hz.